# Procedure: commit after 10000 records

Tags: oracle, plsql, bulk-operations

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testing AS
BEGIN

    insert into t3 select * from t2;

    insert into t1 select * from t4;

commit;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHER THEN
     ROLLBACK;
END;
```

This will work fine

t2 - 3 millions
t4 - 3 millions
total i have 6 million record , due some reason my temp space gets filled so what i want is to commit after every 10000 record is inserted .

how to do?

Comment: The correct solution is to ask your DBA to increase the TEMP tablespace. Any other approach risks data corruption and related integrity issues. Of course a lot of people take the risk because they don't think those things matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `BULK COLLECT` and `FORALL`.

See [Incremental Commit Processing with FORALL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_C31FOQHV7EF6QNRZZADJB57A2.html) and [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) for some examples you can adapt tp your case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet helps.

```
--Test data creation
CREATE TABLE TEST_SO_BULK
AS
SELECT LEVEL COL1,'AVRAJIT'||LEVEL COL2 FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100000;


--Create another table to insert

CREATE TABLE TEST_SO1
AS
SELECT * FROM TEST_SO_BULK
WHERE 1=2;


--Bulk collect with limit clause
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
TYPE lv
IS
  TABLE OF TEST_SO_BULK%ROWTYPE;
  lv_tab lv;
  CURSOR lvsql IS
  SELECT * FROM TEST_SO_BULK;
BEGIN
  OPEN lvsql;
  LOOP
  FETCH lvsql BULK COLLECT INTO lv_tab LIMIT 10000;
  dbms_output.put_line(lv_tab.COUNT);
  FORALL i IN lv_tab.FIRST..lv_tab.LAST
  INSERT INTO TEST_SO1 VALUES
  (
  lv_tab(i).col1,
  lv_tab(i).col2
  );
  EXIT WHEN lvsql%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP; 
END;

--Check data count
select count(1) from test_so1;
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the cursor.  Plus, `EXIT WHEN lv_tab.count = 0`, else you will end up not processing all of the rows your retrieve when there are not an even number of rows. See the "kicking the %NOTFOUND Habit" section here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html